# Downloading and creating empty folder in azure blob with aspcore

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am accessing my azure blob storage with a core service and I can't download a folder from the storage I can't find ways for it any suggestions please....

I need to download a specific folder also I need to create a empty folder can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: download a folder and all files within the folder? and for another issue, no way to create a empty folder on blob storage.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Blob doesn't organize as Folders and Files. If you name a blob with "myfolder\myfile", the explorer shows it as a folder, but that is merely a convenient view, rather than actual folder structure.

So it won't be possible to work on an empty folder in Azure Blobs.

Comment: Hi parkash, thanks but we don't have options to download a single blob (folder with some files or subfolders) completely